# SQL Connection string using ASP.NET and SQL Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, connection-string

I have an intranet website that uses Windows Authentication. 
I have a SQL Server DB that also uses Windows Authentication.

Is there a Connection String I can setup in the Web.config that uses the ASP.NET authentication for SQL, too?

I've tried "Data Source=mysqlserver;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI;" but that uses the apppool's authentication, not the Windows User's authentication.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx

Comment: Scenario1: DB has windows user + Windows Authentication in app.config works? Scenario2: DB has sqlUser + SqlAuthenticate in app.config works?

Comment: Did you try `Integrated Security = True;`?

Comment: @FirebladeDan: #1 did not work because the user the app pool is running under does not have permission to the DB. If it did it would work, but that's not the user that I want the SQL connection running under, I'd like for it to be whoever is currently logged into the site.  #2 does work which is what I am using now, though I'd rather not.

Comment: @ConnorsFan: Yes, I tried that, but it didn't work either as it was using the app pool's user not ASP.NET's user.

Comment: It sounds like you need an SPN to allow the web server service account to impersonate the user when making the second authentication hop to the database. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677949(v=vs.85).aspx